# NLog and final rules

Tags: .net, nlog

Very often I want to exclude logging from a specific chatty logger up to a certain level. Unfortunately, the first of the following rules is final for all levels of that logger, so that the second rule (which is simply my default rule) will not log anything from it:

```
<logger name="ChattyLogger" maxlevel="Warn" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />

<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="default" />
```

One possibility is to use filters instead:

```
<logger name="ChattyLogger" writeTo="blackhole">
  <filters>
    <when condition="level&lt;=LogLevel.Warn" action="IgnoreFinal" />
  </filters>
</logger>

<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="default" />
```

But the syntax is ugly, especially the length and the need to escape the condition expression.

Since this seems like such a common requirement, I'm wondering if I overlooked something.

I'm using nlog under Silverlight, but I presume that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
<logger name="ChattyLogger" maxlevel="Warn"/>
<logger name="ChattyLogger" minlevel="Error" final="true" writeTo="default"/>
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="default" />
```

Comment: Great answer, but surely the first line does nothing, and can be removed?

Comment: @NigelTouch It is needed, because nlog matches a logger by name and level, at least that's what I've noticed. I'm sure you already figured this out, I'm just putting it here for other people. A lost a little time with it, but the version that finally worked for me was:
`<logger name="ChattyLogger" maxlevel="Warn"  final="true" />

<logger name="ChattyLogger" minlevel="Error" final="true" writeTo="default"/>` .Without the `final`on the first rule it defaulted to the global rule "*".

Comment: I spent a half day because I used "Warning" instead of "Warn". Thank you.